# Can an NSTimer take multiple selectors?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to use an `NSTimer` in my app, and was wondering if it's possible to call two methods when the timer fires.

Here's the code:

```
gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector:
Selector("gameMovement" && "fireBullet"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I'm getting an error saying there are two arguments in the Selector.

Comment: Nope, but you can route to a method that invokes the other two, or you can set up two separate timers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. You would call just one method that delegates to all the things you want.

```
func someFunc() {
  gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    0.01,
    target: self,
    selector: Selector("timerFired"),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: true
  )
}

func timerFired() {
  gameMovement()
  fireBullet()
}
```

This is a more maintainable pattern anyway, as it's easier to see how your code flows.